# Exclude a define pattern using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with two columns and want to print the first column only if a determined pattern is not found in the second column, the file can be for example:

```
3   0.
5   0.
4   1.
3   1.
10  0.
```

and I want to print the values in the first column only if there isn't the number 1. in the second file, i.e.

```
3
5
10
```

I know that to print the first column I can use

```
awk  '{print $1}' fileInput >> fileOutput
```

Is it possible to have an if block somewhere?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, you just need to indicate what pattern you don't want to match:

```
awk '! /pattern/' file
```

In this specific case, where you want to print the 1st column of lines where 2st column is *not* "1.", you can say:

```
$ awk '$2 != "1." {print $1}' file
3
5
10
```

When the condition is accomplished, `{print $1}` will be performed, so that you will have the first column of the file.

Comment: In this case, this should do: `awk '!$2 {print $1}'`

Comment: @Jotne my thoughts exactly!

Comment: @Jotne Yes, also thought about it. If the 2nd column is always a number it is fine, but if it is a character it fails. I guess `$2 != 1` sticks better to the requirement.

Comment: Also, the OP did not define what should happen if the value is not 0 and not 1. Specifically `$2!=1` exactly meets the requirements.

Comment: @ziulfer if there are more details you should edit the question.

Comment: thank you guys, I thought that this information wouldn't matter but it turns out I was wrong. My second column has only 0. and 1. with the dots I tried both your solution but they didn't work in this case

Comment: @ziulfer see my update, `$2 != "1."` should make it.

Comment: @ziulfer my answer still works with the dot, as did the old answer here

Comment: @fedorqui It does! thank you. I've tried several brackets options before edit the question, but of course, not this one...

Comment: @TomFenech well, it didn't for me... :(

Comment: @ziulfer Probably you are using a DOS format file? Try `tr -d '\r' < file > new file` or use `awk` with `-F'[ \t\r]*'` ( or even `awk '$2 != "1.\r" {print $1}' `

Comment: @Scrutinizer note you have to refer the OP with a @ to make him/her get a notification. Also, `dos2unix` seems a good tool for this DOS/Unix issues.

Comment: @fedorqui, yes `dos2unix` is a good tool, but it is not always available, unlike `tr -d '\r'` .

Answer (score 2):

In this special case, because the `1` evaluates to `true` and the `0` to `false`, you can do:

```
awk '!$2 { print $1 }' file
3
5
10
```

The part before the `{ }` is the condition under which the commands are executed. In this case, `!$2` means that `not` column 2 is `true` (i.e. column 2 is `false`).

**edit**: this remains to be the case, even with the trailing dot. In fact, all three of these solutions work:

```
bash-4.2$ cat file
3   0.
5   0.
4   1.
3   1.
10  0.
bash-4.2$ awk '!$2 { print $1 }' file       # treat column 2 as a boolean
3
5
10
bash-4.2$ awk '$2 != "1." {print $1}' file  # treat column 2 as a string
3
5
10
bash-4.2$ awk '$2 != 1 {print $1}' file     # treat column 2 as a number
3
5
10
```

Comment: @ziulfer I have added examples showing that each of the options work.

Comment: @ziulfer I would say it depends on the version of your awk. For example, `awk -W version` returns `mawk 1.3.3` to me.